# Game of Life Program

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm working on the following problem from Leetcode:

> Given a board with m by n cells, each cell has an initial state live
>   (1) or dead (0). Each cell interacts with its eight neighbors
>   (horizontal, vertical, diagonal) using the following four rules (taken
>   from the above Wikipedia article):
>
> Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies, as if caused by
>   under-population. Any live cell with two or three live neighbors lives
>   on to the next generation. Any live cell with more than three live
>   neighbors dies, as if by over-population.. Any dead cell with exactly
>   three live neighbors becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction. Write
>   a function to compute the next state (after one update) of the board
>   given its current state.
>
> Follow up:  Could you solve it in-place? Remember that the board needs
>   to be updated at the same time: You cannot update some cells first and
>   then use their updated values to update other cells.

My solution is modeled after the solution offered by another user on the website, so adding their solution description.

> In the beginning, every cell is either 00 or 01. Notice that 1st state
>   is independent of 2nd state. Imagine all cells are instantly changing
>   from the 1st to the 2nd state, at the same time. Let's count # of
>   neighbors from 1st state and set 2nd state bit. Since every 2nd state
>   is by default dead, no need to consider transition 01 -> 00. In the
>   end, delete every cell's 1st state by doing >> 1. For each cell's 1st
>   bit, check the 8 pixels around itself, and set the cell's 2nd bit.
>
> Transition 01 -> 11: when board == 1 and lives >= 2 && lives <= 3.
>   Transition 00 -> 10: when board == 0 and lives == 3.

My code is failing and I'm not sure why. Here's the output vs expected:

```
Input:
[[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
Output:
[[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1,0]]
Expected:
[[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
```

It seems like later rows are being updated based on previous updates in earlier rows, but I believe I accounted for this.. anyone know what the issue is? My solution below:

```
# @param {Integer[][]} board
# @return {Void} Do not return anything, modify board in-place instead.
def game_of_life(board)
    #error conditions
    return nil if (board.nil? || board.length == 0) #empty or nil arr

    row = 0 
    col = 0 
    m = board.length
    n = board[0].length

    until row == m
        col = 0
        until col == n
            live_count = adj_live_counter(board, row, col) #leaving out two conditions because by default second bit is 0
            if alive?(board, row, col) && live_count == 2 || live_count == 3 
                board[row][col] = 3
            elsif dead?(board, row, col) && live_count == 3
                board[row][col] = 2 
            end
            col+=1
        end
        row+=1
    end
    p board 
    #when the above is done, grab second bit for every cell. 
    #board = clear_first_bit(board)
    clear_first_bit(board)
    p board
end 

private 

def adj_live_counter(board, row, col)
    m = board.length 
    n = board[0].length
    count = 0 

    r = [row - 1, 0].max #start: either 0 or the above element
    until r > [row + 1, m - 1].min #end: below element or end of arr
        c = [col - 1, 0].max #start: at left element or 0
        until c > [col + 1, n - 1].min #end: at right element or end of arr
            count += board[r][c] & 1
            #p count 
            c += 1
        end 
        r += 1
    end
    count -=  board[row][col] & 1

    count
end

def clear_first_bit(board)
    m = board.length 
    n = board[0].length

    row = 0 
    col = 0

    until row == m
        col = 0
        until col == n
            board[row][col] >>= 1
            col += 1
        end
        row += 1
    end
end

def alive?(board, row, count)
    board[row][count] & 1 == 1
end

def dead?(board, row, count)
    board[row][count] & 1 == 0
end
```

Solution offered by website (in Java):

```
public void gameOfLife(int[][] board) {
    if (board == null || board.length == 0) return;
    int m = board.length, n = board[0].length;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            int lives = liveNeighbors(board, m, n, i, j);

            // In the beginning, every 2nd bit is 0;
            // So we only need to care about when will the 2nd bit become 1.
            if (board[i][j] == 1 && lives >= 2 && lives <= 3) {  
                board[i][j] = 3; // Make the 2nd bit 1: 01 ---> 11
            }
            if (board[i][j] == 0 && lives == 3) {
                board[i][j] = 2; // Make the 2nd bit 1: 00 ---> 10
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            board[i][j] >>= 1;  // Get the 2nd state.
        }
    }
}

public int liveNeighbors(int[][] board, int m, int n, int i, int j) {
    int lives = 0;
    for (int x = Math.max(i - 1, 0); x <= Math.min(i + 1, m - 1); x++) {
        for (int y = Math.max(j - 1, 0); y <= Math.min(j + 1, n - 1); y++) {
            lives += board[x][y] & 1;
        }
    }
    lives -= board[i][j] & 1;
    return lives;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a precedence problem on these lines:

```
if alive?(board, row, col) && live_count == 2 || live_count == 3 
      board[row][col] = 3
```

This code is parsed as:

```
if (alive?(board, row, col) && live_count == 2) || live_count == 3 
      board[row][col] = 3
```

If you have a dead cell (state 0) that has 3 live neighbors, you change it to state 3 - meaning that it will be alive in the next state and is also now alive in the current state!

Try this instead:

```
if alive?(board, row, col) && (live_count == 2 || live_count == 3) 
      board[row][col] = 3
```